# move semantics and Lifetime of variables when binding lvalue to rvalues reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

just to be sure to well understand what is under the hood... questions are in the code as comments

```
   void test(int && val)
    {
        val=4;
    }//val is  destroyed here ?

int main()
{  
    int nb;
    test(std::move(nb));
    //undefined behavior if I reference here nb ?
    std::cout << nb;
    nb=5;
    std::cin.ignore();    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moved-from value is left in a valid, but unspecified, state. That basically means, as far as I know, that it may contain any value, but it *must* contain some value, and accessing it is legal and defined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that an rvalue reference to something does not magically move the value. All it does is to make it possible to take a non const reference to temporary objects.

This reference is in your example not different from a normal reference, because you don't have any temporaries here. You are the one who has to make the "move" happen.

E.g. if you define that your int is empty when it has a value of `0`, and you write a function that takes an rvalue reference, consumes it and sets the passed value to `0`, then you "moved" the previous value out of your int. After calling this function, it will contain `0`. But that's because *you* defined it like that.

Now, for ints this does not make much sense, but imagine you are handling a pointer to a big piece of memory.

Comment: "You have to understand that an rvalue reference to something does not magically move the value", yeah indeed

Comment: @Guillaume I apologize if I underestimated your expertise, but your question "val is destroyed here?" does not make much sense to me. Val is a reference, so yes, the reference val is destroyed at that point, but the variable that val referenced continues to exist either till it goes out of scope for variables or till the `;` of the expression it was created in for temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is not undefined behavior, because you never actually move from `val` inside your function. `std::move` merely turns `nb` into an rvalue. This actually only makes sense when you have otherwise ambiguous overloads of `test`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//val is  destroy here ?
```

Same answer as if the parameter type was `const int& val`.

```
//undefined behavior if I reference here nb ?
```

No.  However the value printed out is not specified.  This is different than "undefined behavior" which would mean that anything could happen.  If it were undefined behavior would imply your disk could get reformatted.

Comment: Can you explain why the printed value is unspecified in this case? I would have expected it to be well specified, since no actual move operation is performed inside the function.

Comment: I believe that this behavior is indeed well-specified; it sets `nb` to four.  I may be wrong about this, though, so can you clarify why it would have an unspecified value?

Comment: I apparently interpreted the question differently.  If you don't do whole program analysis, then the value of an object being moved from is unspecified.  In this case I purposefully ignored the definition of `test()` when analyzing `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly rvalue references are useful to you when you are writing a new class where you care about the cost of copying it, and you want to write a move constructor.

Using someone else's move constructor (so long as it is well-designed) will be pretty much invisible to you.

eg [When will adding a move constructor and a move assignment operator really start make a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724125/when-will-adding-a-move-constructor-and-a-move-assignment-operator-really-start-m)

So if you want to explore move semantics, I suggest you build some example code using a move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For a good explanation on std::move, please see [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html). Unless you don't start using the move constructor, you would not be effectively using this new feature. Also, I don't think it makes any sense for primitive types where copying has no overhead.